# An Estimate Of/On

Tags: prepositions

I have question about the choice of "*of*" and "*on*" here:

> 1. We don't have an ***estimate of*** the cost of the repairs.
> 2. We don't have an ***estimate on*** the cost of the repairs.

A search of the web shows that both "*an estimate* ***of***" and "*an estimate* ***on***" are used.  What do native speakers think?

Comment: estimate *for* is also possible! However, in a different case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I feel that estimate of is better. However, it would flow smoother if you said something like "We don't have an estimate of how much the repairs will cost". Estimate of refers to a general amount.

Comment: So, "*estimate* ***on***" is not good?

Comment: @meatie Native speakers would not use estimate on. I hope this helps. Please +1 if you don't mind and my answers works for you.

Comment: So, would [this](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/09/03/us/military-payday-shift-yields-budget-pay-dirt.html) 
 be wrong?  
"Although no one has ventured to put ***an estimate on*** the tax loss, military personnel on active duty will get a one-time tax break in exchange for putting up with the one-time shift in pay dates."

Comment: I am not necessarily saying it is wrong. The article uses formal language, which uses a different style of wording than conversation.